# GNU Make unnecessarily re-running pattern rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple linear data processing pipeline that needs to be run for multiple input files, so I've specified this process as a set of Make rules:

```
file1.abc: file1.input
    do some stuff

file1.def: file1.abc
    do some stuff

file1.ghi: file1.def some_script.py
    do some stuff
```

...etc.

When I run `make file1.ghi` everything works fine. And, if I update some_script.py and run the command again, only the final step is re-run, as I would expect.

Now if I rewrite my Makefile to be more general and work for files other than file1:

```
all: $(patsubst %.input, %.ghi, $(wildcard *.input))

%.abc: %.input
    do some stuff

%.def: %.abc
    do some stuff

%.ghi: %.def some_script.py
    do some stuff
```

...and run `make`, it will create all of my products automatically. However, if I make a change to some_script.py and run `make` again, it re-runs the entire pipeline, not just the last step, for each output file. I would expect that since only a dependency of the final step has changed, only the final step would be re-run. I suspect the problem is my incomplete understanding of how Make handles dependencies.

Why is this happening, and is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intermediate files are probably being deleted. From the GNU make manual:

> Section 10.4 Chains of Implicit Rules
>
> [...]
>
> The second difference is that if 'make' *does* create B in order to
> update something else, it deletes B later on after it is no longer
> needed.  Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before
> 'make' also does not exist after 'make'.  'make' reports the deletion
> to you by printing a 'rm -f' command showing which file it is deleting.

In order to avoid this, declare the targets with `.SECONDARY` (`.PRECIOUS` has the same effect but also avoids deleting the files if `make` is interrupted, which you probably don't want.) E.g.

> .SECONDARY: %.def

Comment: Don't forget to mention the solution: `.SECONDARY: %.def`.

Comment: That's right. The solution was to use .PRECIOUS to protect those intermediate files from being deleted. Thank you! (Or apparently .SECONDARY would also have worked - is there a difference?)

Comment: Experimenting, I have found that patterns like `%.def` don't actually work with the `.SECONDARY` target, and this is consistent with the manual. `.PRECIOUS` should be used instead.